# Проблема с кодировкой utf-8

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Проблема в кодировке при получении данных из консоли

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            do
            {
            
                Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                
                Console.WriteLine("Введите имя");
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Приветствую " + str);
               
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Выбивает в консоле

Введите имя

(мой ввод)Джо

Приветствую ???

[image: скриншот]

Если добавить код `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`
то вообще не выбивает символы[image: скриншот]

Comment: Запустил у себя ваш код и такой ошибки не обнаружил. Но у меня мультиплатформенный ASP.NET Core проект. Возможно это заключается в выборе платформы, распишите какая у вас платформа.

Comment: Ноут из Польши, и скорее всего в винде другая кодировка. .NET Framework

Comment: А в чем необходимость использовать именно UTF8? Его поддержка и в Windows, и в C#, намного хуже, чем UTF16.

Comment: А почему не задать Console.InputEncoding дополнительно?

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой при использовании в консоли кирилицы на английских версиях Windows+Visual Studio (2022.
Почему не работает "Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8" так и не смог понять с документации, зато прекрасно работает вариант:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Console.InputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
```

Comment: InputEncoding ставить в UTF8 бесполезно из-за старого бага в conhost

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43295